# Run Python script from VBA Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, anaconda, command-prompt

I am trying to run a simple python by pressing a button in excel.
The VBA script which is assigned to the button

```
Sub RunPY()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe As String
Dim PythonScript As String

'Create a shell object
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

PythonExe = "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"
'PythonExe = "C:\Users\SAMSALEH\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"

PythonScript = """N:\SCRIPT\script.py"""

'objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
objShell.Run "cmd /k" & " " & PythonExe & " " & PythonScript
Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

The script uses numpy and other libraries. However, when I run the script I get the following error in the command prompt:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:143: UserWarning: mkl-service `package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box 

operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service`
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\SCRIPT\Pressure.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

I went through the different fixes suggested online, I created a new environment in conda and activated it.
and the script runs finely in spyder.

Any suggested solution?

Comment: install numpy using conda, u might installed numpy using pip so just install it again using conda install numpy. similar problem i faced and the methods worked for me.